# Using 'groupby' without aggregation and sorting within groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have [countries_of_the_world.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/fernandol/countries-of-the-world). Basically, it's the table with the following bits of information:

```
Country    Region             GDP
Austria    Western Europe     100
Chad       Africa             30
```

I need to sort GDP values in descending order by region with countries inside these regions. It should look like:

```
Region     Country        GDP
Africa     Egypt          42
           Chad           30
           Kongo          28
Oceania    Australia      120
           New Zealand    100
           Indonesia      50
```

I tried 'groupby' but it doesn't work without aggregation function applied so I tried lambda but it didn't sort correctly:

```
countries.sort_values(['GDP'], ascending=False).groupby(['Region','Country']).aggregate(lambda x:x)
```

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and then convert `Region` and `Country` to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = (countries.sort_values(['Region','GDP'], ascending=[True, False])
                .set_index(['Region','Country']))
print (df1)
                     GDP
Region  Country         
Africa  Egypt         42
        Chad          30
        Kongo         28
Oceania Australia    120
        New Zealand  100
        Indonesia     50
```